# MySQL Non-Negative INT Columns

Tags: mysql

I want to do the following query:

```
UPDATE `users` SET balance = (balance - 10) WHERE id=1
```

But if the balance will become a negative number I want an error to be returned. Any ideas on if this is possible?

Answer (score 6):

If you do

```
UPDATE `users` SET balance = (balance - 10) WHERE id=1 and balance >=10
```

You should be able to detect that a row was not modified.

Note that while another answer suggests using an unsigned int column, this may not work:

Create a test table

```
create table foo(val int unsigned default '0');
insert into foo(val) values(5);
```

Now we attempt to subtract 10 from our test row:

```
update foo set val=val-10;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1

mysql> select * from foo;
+------------+
| val        |
+------------+
| 4294967295 |
+------------+
```

This was on mysql 5.0.38

Comment: Thank you Paul - I like your method - I'll return the amount of rows affected and if it is 0 I know the balance is to low.

Comment: Odd that the error is inconsistent.  I'm getting it on 5.0.45

Answer (score 5):

You can make the balance field of the users table an unsigned int:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `balance` `balance` INT UNSIGNED;
```

Comment: You beat me to it by a few seconds. MySQL will return a "#1264 - Out of range value adjusted for column 'balance'" error for negative numbers on an unsigned field

Comment: I didn't get that result:

create table tmp2 (val int unsigned default '0');
insert into tmp2(val)values(5);
update tmp2 set val=val-10;
select * from tmp2;
+------------+
| val        |
+------------+
| 4294967295 |
+------------+

Comment: hmm, difficult to read! suffice to say, when I subtract 10 from an unsigned int column containing 5, I get no error and a new value of 4294967295 on mysql 5.0.38

Comment: and if business logic changes to allow $100 debt, you are back at square one.

Comment: I have the same result as Paul Dixon - I also tried it before posting here

Comment: On my local instance of MySQL 5.0.67 I get a #1264 warning and it sets the value to 0.

Comment: This can result in the value wrapping around to a massive positive value. If this is dealing with money, that would be baaaad.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of things is done by [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html). MySql have support for triggers only since 5.0.2.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER balance_check BEFORE INSERT ON user FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.balance < @limit_value THEN
        -- do something that causes error. 
        -- mysql doesn't have mechanism to block action by itself
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Triggers in MySql are quite rudimentary. You have to hack things around to do some things (e.g. cause error).

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do this with a simple query. you should use a mysql user defined function that manage that before update the row. or a trigger

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip that wouldn't fit as a comment.  I was just trying to subtract 32000 from 32047 (not a negative result) and was getting errors.  Also confusing, I was getting BIGINT errors but my subtraction was on a SMALLINT column! (Which still makes no sense.)

If you're getting "out of range" errors even when your "balance" is positive, try adding "limit 1" to the end of your query.  Maybe this is a bug in MySQL?

```
mysql> update posts set cat_id=cat_id-32000 where timestamp=1360870280;
ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`xxxxx`.`posts`.`cat_id` - 32000)'

mysql> update posts set cat_id=cat_id-32000 where timestamp=1360870280 limit 1; 
Query OK, 1 row affected (6.45 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

In my case the timestamp is unique (I just checked to be sure) but not explicitly defined as unique when I created the table.  So why is the "limit 1" here necessary?  But who cares, it works!